# Como puedo obtener el arbol o una rama de la tareas que pertenecen a un grupo en particular

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla en sqlserver y me gustaría obtener todos los registros de tareas que estén relacionados con solo un IdTareaInv

```
| Tipo      | IdTareaInv  | IdProyectoInv | Titulo                                    | IdTareaInvOrigen | Horas |
| --------- | ----------- | ------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------------- | ----- |
| Principal |15639        | 1748          | Revisión y seguimiento                    | NULL             | 8     |
| Asociada  |15640        | 1748          |            Revisión y seguimiento         | 15639            | 8     |
| Principal |15641        | 1748          | Buffer Overflow                           | NULL             | 8     |
| Asociada  |15642        | 1748          |           Buffer Overflow                 | 15641            | 4     |
| Principal |15643        | 1748          | Cifrado TLS v1 Activado                   | NULL             | 6     |
| Principal |15645        | 1748          | Listado usuarios Apache                   | NULL             | 4     |
| Principal |15646        | 1748          | Librería bootstrap desactualizada         | NULL             | 10    |
| Asociada  |15727        | 1748          |       Tarea Primera de segundo nivel      | 15646            | 2     |
| Asociada  |15731        | 1748          |           Otra Tarea Primera de Tercer n  | 15727            | 1     |
| Asociada  |15728        | 1748          |       Tarea Segunda de segundo nivel      | 15646            | 4     |
| Asociada  |15729        | 1748          |           Primera del Tercer Nivel de la  | 15728            | 1     |
| Asociada  |15730        | 1748          |           Segunda del Tercer Nivel de la  | 15728            | 2     |
| Principal |15647        | 1748          | Revisión cabeceras HTTP                   | NULL             | 2     |
```

Por ejemplo si en la condición de la sentencia es IdTareaInv = 15728 o cualquier otro Id que se encuentre en el grupo de tareas relacionadas debe retornar toda la jerarquía de ese grupo de tareas, Algo Así:

```
| Tipo      | IdTareaInv  | IdProyectoInv | Titulo                                    | IdTareaInvOrigen | Horas |
| --------- | ----------- | ------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------------- | ----- |
| Principal |15646        | 1748          | Librería bootstrap desactualizada         | NULL             | 10    |
| Asociada  |15727        | 1748          |       Tarea Primera de segundo nivel      | 15646            | 2     |
| Asociada  |15731        | 1748          |           Otra Tarea Primera de Tercer n  | 15727            | 1     |
| Asociada  |15728        | 1748          |       Tarea Segunda de segundo nivel      | 15646            | 4     |
| Asociada  |15729        | 1748          |           Primera del Tercer Nivel de la  | 15728            | 1     |
| Asociada  |15730        | 1748          |           Segunda del Tercer Nivel de la  | 15728            | 2     |
```

Esta son las sentencias que utilice, ¿Existe una forma mas directa?

```
Declare @IdTareaPrincipal int
    -- CTE Recursiva para obtener de forma ascendente los IdtareaInv de una OT Asociada hasta llegar a la OT Principal  
    ;WITH CTE_TareasAsc(IdTareaInv, IdTareaInvOrigen, HorasEstimadas, Nivel) AS   
    (  
        SELECT IdTareaInv, IdTareaInvOrigen, HorasEstimadas, 1 AS Nivel FROM [T-Inversion-Tareas] WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE IdTareaInv = @IdTareaOT  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT T.IdTareaInv, T.IdTareaInvOrigen, T.HorasEstimadas, Nivel - 1 FROM [T-Inversion-Tareas] T WITH(NOLOCK)  
        INNER JOIN CTE_TareasAsc R ON T.IdTareaInv  = R.IdTareaInvOrigen     
    )
    SELECT @IdTareaPrincipal = IdTareaInv FROM CTE_TareasAsc WHERE IsNull(IdTareaInvOrigen,0) = 0  
    -- CTE recursiva a partir de la Tarea Principal de la anterior CTE asi obtenemos la jerarquía de todas las tareas asociadas a la principal
    ;WITH CTE_ReporteTareas(IdTareaInv, Titulo, IdTareaInvOrigen, HorasEstimadas, InicioEstimado, FinEstimado, Nivel) AS   
    (  
        SELECT IdTareaInv , Titulo, IdTareaInvOrigen, HorasEstimadas, InicioEstimado, FinEstimado, 1 AS Nivel 
        FROM [T-Inversion-Tareas] WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE IdTareaInv = @IdTareaPrincipal   
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT T.IdTareaInv, T.Titulo, T.IdTareaInvOrigen, T.HorasEstimadas, T.InicioEstimado, T.FinEstimado, Nivel + 1 
        FROM [T-Inversion-Tareas] T WITH(NOLOCK)  
        INNER JOIN CTE_ReporteTareas R ON T.IdTareaInvOrigen  = R.IdTareaInv   
    )  
    SELECT IdTareaInv, Titulo, IdTareaInvOrigen, HorasEstimadas, InicioEstimado, FinEstimado, Nivel 
    FROM CTE_ReporteTareas ORDER BY Nivel; 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Por el momento estoy utilizando 2 CTE una que asciende por la jerarquía a partir de un IdTarea hasta llegar a la tarea Principal de la rama y luego utilizo otra CTE para descender por todos las tareas vinculadas desde la Tarea Principal. Realmente quisiera saber si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Gracias

Comment: Cuál CTE? Por favor, evita la aproximación "hagan ustedes y yo miro" y prueba con la aproximación "miren cómo lo hago, tengo X duda sobre esta aproximación, tengo este error, etc". [edit] la pregunta y añadir tu aproximación y cualquier error o problema es el camino a respuestas útiles